# Uncountable all in

Tags: all-in

During a game of poker , if when someone goes “all -in” then shoves all of their chips into the pot without counting them , what do you do? 5 other players have stakes in and the pot is large as is. Numerous bets and calls have already been played (7 card stud) the pot is unknown but large and now a player has mixed their unknown amount of chips into the unknown pot. All at a home poker night game ,do we try to replay all bets to maybe determine the players all- in amount or?

Answer (score 2):

Bets are *never* pushed into the pot in a poker game. Bets are made in front of the player, between his stack and the pot, and must be countable. If you "splashed the pot" in a casino, you'd be expelled.

In a home game, you'll just have to figure it out as best you can and not invite the asshole back next week.

Comment: I would never say never here. It happens. When it does you deal with it. Maybe kick someone out,